# Can I pass a className as a prop to StyledComponent in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a simple button component with actions passed as props. I've decided to style it using **Styled-Components**.

In my React Application, I have three buttons with different actions and I would like them to have a different color.

Can I write some **CSS classes** inside StyledComponent and **pass as a prop** and 'indicator' which class should my component be styled?

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52321539/

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this is one of the most basic features of styled components.

One way is to create different components:

```
const MyButton = styled.button`
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
`;

const FooButton = styled(MyButton)`
  color: red;
`;

const BooButton = styled(MyButton)`
  color: blue;
`;
```

Another way is to use props:

```
const MyButton = styled.button`
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: ${({type}) => type === 'foo' ? 'red' : 'blue'};
`;
...
... 
<MyButton type={'foo'} />
```

And for your original question, you can do that. But in most cases it's less "styled-components"ish to use classNames that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can style classes inside inside styled-components like this:

```
const Button = styled.button`
  &.className {
    // some styles
  }
```